# Java HashMap losing value on loop iteration

Tags: java, android, dictionary, hashmap

i'm attempting to reorder an List of Maps in alphabetical order.  i can see that the "name" String gets filled out with the appropriate value, but groupDataCopy is never updated.  as far as i know, using the new operator and calling "put" will place the value in the Map.  but I can see that on the following iteration, the ArrayList contains:

```
 {name = null}
```

i don't know why i'm losing values in my Map List.  here is the code:

```
private void sortByName() {
    List<Map<String, String>> groupDataCopy = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    List<List<Map<String, String>>> childDataCopy = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();
    int groupPos = 0;
    int nextNamePos = 0;
    String name = null;

    while(groupPos<groupData.size()) {
        //main loop
        int groupDataComparison = 0;
        name = null;

        while(groupDataComparison<groupData.size()) {
            //comparison traversal for group
            if(!groupDataCopy.isEmpty()) {  //if groupDataCopy has data
                if(groupDataCopy.get(groupDataCopy.size()-1).get("name").compareTo(groupData.get(groupDataComparison).get("name")) > 0) {   //if the last index of groupDataCopy is alphabetically after (or equal to) last chosen name
                    if(name==null || groupData.get(groupDataComparison).get("name").compareTo(name) < 0) {
                        name = groupData.get(groupDataComparison).get("name");
                        nextNamePos = groupDataComparison;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if(name==null || groupData.get(groupDataComparison).get("name").compareTo(name) < 0) {
                    name = groupData.get(groupDataComparison).get("name");
                    nextNamePos = groupDataComparison;
                }
            }
            groupDataComparison++;
        }
        groupDataCopy.add(new HashMap<String, String>());
        groupDataCopy.get(groupPos).put("name", name);
        childDataCopy.add(new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>());
        for(Map<String, String> data : childData.get(nextNamePos)) {
            childDataCopy.get(groupPos).add(data);
        }
        groupPos++;
    } 

    groupData = groupDataCopy;
    childData = childDataCopy;
}
```

Comment: Protip: any time you have `List<List<Map<K,V>>>` it's time you made some classes out of it.

Comment: found out that the comparator in my code is simply giving the wrong values.  for comparing "Alice Martin" to "Susan Dye" i get the integer (-18) where i should be getting a positive number.  why is the compareTo method giving erroneous data?  (also tried compareToIgnoreCase, same result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Comparator<Map<String, String> comparator = new Comparator<Map<String, String>()
{
    public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) 
    {
        return o1.get("name").compartTo(o2.get("name");
    }
}

Collections.sort(groupData, comparator);
```

Comment: but how do i get the childData sorted with the group data?  the childData contains a List of phone numbers associated with each group.

Comment: Could you use java.util.TreeMap?  It sorts a map by its keys.

Comment: that's fine, but i'm not sorting the Map; i'm sorting the List on one of the Map's values.

Comment: By creating the compartor you are tellling the Collections.sort() method to sort by the name value.  Therefore the List<Map<String, String>> groupData will be ordered by the value of "name" in each map.

As mentioned by glowcode I would create a class that ties the two together.  Then you could create a compartor that compares on that class instead by getting the group map out of the class.  The end result would be a sorted list of your custom class sorted by the value "name" in the group map.

Comment: found out that the comparator in my code is simply giving the wrong values.  for comparing "Alice Martin" to "Susan Dye" i get the integer (-18) where i should be getting a positive number.  why is the compareTo method giving erroneous data?  (also tried compareToIgnoreCase, same result).

Comment: "Alice Martin" to "Susan Dye" i get the integer (-18)"  That is correct.  A is less than S.

Comment: i switched the objects in the first compare and it works perfectly now... /feellikeidiot.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Comparator that will let you use Collections.sort:

Something like:

```
Comparator<Map<String, String> comp = new Comparator<Map<String, String>()
{
    public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) 
    {
        //write code to compare values
    }
}
```

After which you can simply do:

```
Collections.sort(groupData, comp);
```

Comment: but how do i get the childData sorted with the group data?  the childData contains a List of phone numbers associated with each group.

Comment: If the keys match, do you really need to sort it?  This seems to defeat the purposes of using maps to begin with and I'm inclined to agree with glowcoder that you may want to abstract this into objects so that you can simply implement Comparable and be done with it.

Comment: it can't be done really.  the lists are expected parameters of SimpleExpandableListAdapter in the Android API.

Comment: found out that the comparator in my code is simply giving the wrong values.  for comparing "Alice Martin" to "Susan Dye" i get the integer (-18) where i should be getting a positive number.  why is the compareTo method giving erroneous data?  (also tried compareToIgnoreCase, same result).